# Potential issue with regression model

Tags: regression, survival-analysis, cox-regression

A very broad question I had asked but my set up like this. So I took a data that was published in 2013-14 when nejm paper for AML came out, so the criteria i took is FAB classification then , Cytogenetic risk and other clinical factor. Then another study published in 2018-19 called BeatAML which had again same criteria but the FAB classification were bit more refined where as in 2013-14 it was bit primitive sort of.

So my initial model was with the old data that was my test model and the new one is for my validation cohort to predict patient survival. Now  i do see if i follow new classification my old analysis will be modified a bit as samples with be again reassigned to one or the other group which  i don't want to do as my paper is in final stage.

Now how do i justify or what would be the error with the approach or potential question that might come.

I would like to hear from stats people who can guide me.

Any suggestion or help will be really appreciated

Comment: This type of domain-specific question is much better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/. Stackoverflow is intended for programming-related questions, per [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). For the situation you've described, I would probably keep the paper as is and explain in the discussion why you haven't used the 'newer' FAB classification scheme, then while the paper is under review rebuild the model using the modern classification scheme and see if it makes a difference. If 'newer' FAB is the same, add that into the discussion.

Comment: Also, if coxph modelling shows 'FAB classification' is not significantly associated with survival (i.e. p>0.05) it makes things easier i.e. "there are many similar methods for classifying acute leukemia, however due to the relatively small contribution of this variable to the model we do not expect a significant change in the accuracy of predictions if a different classification scheme is used". If classification is significant then I think you need to 'start from scratch' and relabel patients using the modern scheme and rebuild your model. Hope this helps; good luck!

Comment: thank you Dr @jared_mamrot making my life easier with proper way to look into